# One-loop correction to $F^2$ in massless QED, question from Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, quantum-anomalies

In Peskin & Schroeder chapter 19, about trace anomaly in massless QED, the trace of $\Theta^{\mu\nu}$ is given by
$$ {\Theta^\mu} _\mu =-\frac{4-d}{4} (F_{\lambda\sigma})^2 + (1-d) \bar{\psi} i  \displaystyle{\not}D \psi. \tag{19.159}$$
The one-loop matrix element of $ {\Theta^\mu} _\mu$ is given by the following three diagrams.

[image]

I do not understand these diagrams.
Just as the explanation in   P&S, the expectation of $(1-d) \bar{\psi} i  \displaystyle{\not}D \psi $ is zero, the one-loop matrix element is from the first term which is can be written as
$$-\frac{4-d}{2}A_\mu(-k) (k^2g^{\mu\nu}-k^\mu k^\nu)A_\nu(k).$$
This seems to be the usual photon propagator with some projection operator inserted. Why not from the usual diagrams like the followings?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what your exact question is?

Answer (score 2):

In each diagram in Fig. 19.10, the two external photon lines are from the external background photon field ($A^\mu$ or $A^\nu$), and the cross-dot corresponds to one of the three terms in ${\Theta^\mu}_\mu$ as in (19.159).

In ${\Theta^\mu}_\mu$ as in (19.159), we have $F_{\lambda\sigma}F^{\lambda\sigma}$ and $\bar{\Psi}i\displaystyle{\not}D\Psi$.

$F_{\lambda\sigma}F^{\lambda\sigma}$ gives us (19.158) with a different factor. This, when combined with a 1-loop, gives us the third diagram.

$\bar{\Psi}i\displaystyle{\not}D\Psi = \bar{\Psi}i\displaystyle{\not}\partial\Psi + \bar{\Psi}i\displaystyle{\not}A\Psi$. The first term, combined with a 1-loop, gives us the first diagram in Fig. 19.10. The second term, combined with a 1-loop, gives us the second diagram.

Also, the last $k^2$ in (19.161) may be a bit confusing. It is from the following equality.

$$(k^2 g^{\mu\sigma} - k^\mu k^\sigma) (k^2 g^{\sigma\nu} - k^\sigma k^\mu) = (k^2 g^{\mu\nu} - k^\mu k^\nu) k^2$$